# Spring Boot URL Mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was trying to research this specific problem online but I don't really know what to search up on Google.
My question is: is there a way to auto-redirect a url to another url. For example: I type
`http://localhost:8080` which directs you to `http://localhost:8080/`
I was wondering if I could make it so `http://localhost:8080` redirect to `http://localhost:8080/home`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following status `HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT` to indicate that this URL(`/`) is permanently moved and use `Location` header to indicate what is the new location(`/home`).

```
public class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> sayHello1() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT)
         .header("Location", "/home").build();
    }

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> sayHello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
         .body(Collections.singletonMap("message", "Hello world!"));
    }    
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This can be done with the `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT)` annotation on the method as well :)

Answer (score 0):

this is works for me.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "")
    public ModelAndView redirect(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String redirectUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString() + "home";
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestController {
  @GetMapping(value = "/")
  public String home() {
     return "redirect:/home";
  }
}
```

You should not put **@ResponseBody** annotation in method definition else the redirect will not work.